# Is it safe to call placement new on address of elements in std::array?

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, placement-new

I want to reuse memory declared in std::array. So at the beginning, declare a variable:

```
std::array<S, 1024> pool;
```

Then I want destroy some elements and reuse it for other purpose:

```
(&pool[24])->~S();
new (&pool[24])->S();
```

Is it safe? What should I take care of?

Comment: "I want to reuse memory declared in `std::array`" No, you probably don't. What purpose does this serve? What specific problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: whats wrong with `pool[24] = S{};` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The copy constructor or assign operator are disabled.

Comment: @tadman For reusage of memory.

Comment: That's not a compelling reason. What technical problem are you trying to solve? This reeks of premature and unnecessary optimization, but I could be wrong. How big is `S`? How many times do you do this allocation operation?

Comment: `std::array<S,1024> pool{};` will already give you a set of default initialized S's No need for copy or assignment at all.

Comment: @tadman About 200 bytes per S, with a dsp dvice contained. Not to much, but we want to limit the device count peak.

Comment: well, assignment and copy being deleted is something to be considered. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: IIRC before C++20 this was not safe if your object had const or reference members.

Comment: Note that if the constructor of `S` can throw, you can get into troubles (undefined behavior).

Comment: @NathanOliver If a type can be placed in std::array, could it be with a referance member?

Comment: it's possible but it would have to be a type where the reference has a default value or refers to another member of the class.

Comment: @DanielLangr If the constructor throws you are in trouble too. The destructor of the array will destruct the object again.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I don't understand your comment. My notice was about the constructor.

Comment: @DanielLangr Sorry, I mend when the destructor throws.

Answer (score 1):

Since c++20 this is perfectly legal as long as both the destructor and constructor are called. If they throw an exception then you are in trouble. At some point the destructor for the array will call `~S()` again and if there isn't a living object in the array things will go badly.

So in summary: It's dangerous.

A better solution, if you don't want to use heap allocated objects, would be to create a Memory Resource with the size of 1024 `S`  and an allocator for it and use that.